# Add EventListener to dynamic child angular

Tags: angular, addeventlistener

I want to add an eventListener on my childEvent but i don't know how to do.

I'm dynamically creating components inside SchemaExploitationComponent using the ViewContainerRef.createComponent() method, which returns a ComponentRef object.

I need to dynamically add an event listener to this component so it will call  the ajouterEvenement method defined inside SchemaExploitationComponent.

### Parent Class :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-schema-exploitation',
  template: ` <div #parent (evenement)="ajouterEvenement($event)"></div> `
  styleUrls: ['./schema-exploitation.component.css']
})
export class SchemaExploitationComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  ajouterEvenement(evenement) {
    console.log(evenement);
  }

  ouvrirModal(evenement: string) {


    if (evenement == "Alarme")
    {
      let comp:ComponentFactory<RegroupementAlarmeComponent> = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(RegroupementAlarmeComponent);
      var alarmeComponent = this.container.createComponent(comp);
      alarmeComponent.instance._ref = alarmeComponent;

    }
    if (evenement == "Appel Client")
    {
     // here dynamic component created

     let comp:ComponentFactory<RegroupementAppelClientComponent> = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(RegroupementAppelClientComponent);
      let appelClientComponent = this.container.createComponent(comp);
      appelClientComponent.instance._ref = appelClientComponent;
    }
    if (evenement == "TD")
    {

      let comp:ComponentFactory<RegroupementTdComponent> = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(RegroupementTdComponent);
      var tdComponent = this.container.createComponent(comp);
      tdComponent.instance._ref = tdComponent;
    }
  }

  constructor(
    protected schema: SchemaExploitationService,
    protected route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    });
  }
}
```

### Dynamic child class :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-regroupement-alarme',
  template: `
             <buttontype="button" label="Valider" (click)="ajouterAlarme()"></button> 
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./regroupement-alarme.component.css']
})
export class RegroupementAlarmeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() evenement = new EventEmitter<Alarme>();
  _ref:any;
  alarme:Alarme = new Alarme();

  removeObject()
  {
    this._ref.destroy();
  }
  ajouterAlarme()
  {
    this.evenement.emit(this.alarme);
    this.removeObject();
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want to pass the object "Alarme" from my child component to my parentComponent using an EventEmmitter but it's like my parent don't listen to my event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
  alarmeObjectFromChild: any;

  ouvrirModal(evenement: string) {


    if (evenement == "Alarme")
    {
      let comp:ComponentFactory<RegroupementAlarmeComponent> = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(RegroupementAlarmeComponent);
      var alarmeComponent = this.container.createComponent(comp);
      alarmeComponent.instance.evenement.subscribe((alarmeObjectYouWant) => {
        this.alarmeObjectFromChild = alarmeObjectYouWant;
        //do whatever you want
      })
      alarmeComponent.instance._ref = alarmeComponent;

    }
  }
```

Here you have github repo for the solution https://github.com/solenski/stackoverflow47683459.git

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer so others can benefit from it as well :) You're welcome